# PHP only shows in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, hyperlink

New to PHP, I'm trying to do an exercise which consists on making a simple dynamic website with people information, linked to a local database.

But I'm stuck at a point where I can only show anything through a foreach loop.

My database looks like this (with more people of course) :

```
<?php 

function getAllPerson() {
$list_person = array();

$person1 = array(
"id" => 0,
"surname" => "John",
"name" => "Doe",
"img" => "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/64.jpg");
$liste_person[0] = $person1;

return array($personne1);
}

function getPerso($person_id) {
$list_person = getAllPerson();
return $list_person[$person_id];
}
```

And my page :

```
<?php 
require_once 'model/database.php';
$id = $_GET["id"];
$person = getPerso($id);
$list_person = getAllPerson();
require_once 'layout/header.php'; ?>

        <section class="row">

            <article class="column">
                <h2><?php echo $person['name'] ?> <?php echo $person['surname'] ?></h2>
                <img src="<?php echo $person['img'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $person['name'] ?> <?php echo $person['surname'] ?>" class="pull-left thumbnail">


            </article>
        </section>
```

But nothing works (there is more html code but I wanted to keep it short here)..

But when I do a foreach and put the article in :

```
<?php foreach ($list_person as $person) : ?>
```

Everything shows, but the 4 persons at the same time (which is logical, it's a foreach).

And I have to admit I don't know how to make it an independent page for every different "id" there is. Can you help me with that? Keep it simple please!

Thank you very much!

Comment: what's the id you are calling ? `id=??`

Comment: It's the "id" in the database, which stands for the person's number in the array.

Comment: What you mean by "PHP only shows in foreach" ? are you trying to display  the info for only one particular id ?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I only put one id in the database, but there could supposedly be 100. There is a homepage with a foreach loop for every "id" that links to a single profile page, the one I'm stuck with.

Comment: Are you representing N users like this $liste_person[n] = $personN ?

Comment: Hm, I don't get the question, sorry !

Comment: You may wanna consider using [classes](http://phpio.net/s/377s).

Answer (score 0):

I made it short check this if you can use it :

```
function getAllPerson($id = null) {

$list_person = array();

   $person1 = array(
      "id" => 0,
       "surname" => "John",
       "name" => "Doe",
       "img" => "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/64.jpg");

   $person2 = array(
       "id" => 1,
       "surname" => "Sam",
       "name" => "Parker",
       "img" => "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/65.jpg");

    $list_person[0] = $person1;
    $list_person[1] = $person2;

   if($id == null){
       return ($list_person);
   }
   else{
    return $list_person[$id];
   }
}
```

Now you can call this function in your page

```
<?php $person = getAllPerson(1); ?>

<?php if(!empty($person)) { ?>

<section class="row">

        <article class="column">
            <h2><?php echo $person['name'] ?> <?php echo $person['surname'] ?></h2>
            <img src="<?php echo $person['img'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $person['name'] ?> <?php echo $person['surname'] ?>" class="pull-left thumbnail">


        </article>
</section>

<?php } ?>
```

You can use the same function, if you want to get all the users, just leave the argument field empty : like getAllPerson().

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting closer: the rest of the section doesn't disappear, but the print_r($person) now shows the complete array, and what it contains doesn't want to show on screen... 
The id in "function getAllPerson($id = null)" seems to be unused in its scope. Do I need to define it ?

Comment: Thats what i mentioned, You can pass an id to load specific person, i you dont pass an id you will get all the person.

Comment: My problem is more in the "why doesn't it appear"... It seems to be the core of my problem, I've tried numerous solutions, but it always comes back to this: what is in the database just doesn't want to show.

Comment: @Solomai what you are trying to display ? , If you want to display the person with id : 1 just call the function getAllPerson(1), you will only get that person. similarly if you want to display person with id 20 call function  getAllPerson(20)

Comment: I'm trying to display the information I should get with a <?php echo $person ['xx'] ?>. But it just doesn't work on my side ! ^^

Comment: first load $person = getAllPerson(xx), then try to print with $person['id'], $person['name'] etc

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my problem was waaaay off, and I wasn't looking at the right place. The code was clean, my only problem was the $_GET['id'] was pointing to nowhere... Hassan Ahmed was right. I just forgot to make my page dynamic by changing the page name depending on the person I was looking at, so it could not show anything.

Thanks a lot for your answers though, I could understand more some things by practicing with what you gave me !